# How to UPDATE mysql using implode array

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a form with multiple checkboxes. the value of checkboxes is stored in the mysql database and and `INSERT` query is working fine when i try to update record with `UPDATE` query something went wrong i have this `index.php`

This is my insert query which is working fine

```
$hobi=implode(',',$_POST['hobi']);

$db->query("INSERT INTO info (cekbox) VALUES('$hobi')");
```

And this is my update query which is not working means not updating records

```
$hobi=implode(',',$_POST['hobi']);

//$db->query("INSERT INTO info (cekbox) VALUES('$hobi')");

$db->query("UPDATE info (cekbox) WHERE id= '$id' SET VALUES ('$hobi') ");
```

Please tell me how to put implode array in update query?

Comment: Think about SQL Injection - you should escape `$hobi` or use prepared statements

Comment: @Philipp how to escape `$hobi`.I am new to php.

Comment: use pdo prepared statement for maximum protection from sql injection..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your update statement wrong. This has nothing to do with the `implode()`.

```
$db->query("UPDATE info SET cekbox='$hobi' WHERE id= '$id'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't treat UPDATE query as INSERT query

```
$db->query("UPDATE `info` SET `cekbox`='".$hobi."' WHERE `id`= $id");
```

Answer (score 0):

your update sql is incorrect:

```
UPDATE info (cekbox) WHERE id= '$id' SET VALUES ('$hobi')
// should be:
UPDATE info SET cekbox = '$hobi' WHERE id= '$id';
```